# Good error handling with file_get_contents

Tags: php, error-handling

I am making use of [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) which has this funciton:

```
// get html dom form file
function file_get_html() {
    $dom = new simple_html_dom;
    $args = func_get_args();
    $dom->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);
    return $dom;
}
```

I use it like so:

```
$html3 = file_get_html(urlencode(trim("$link")));
```

Sometimes, a URL may just not be valid and I want to handle this. I thought I could use a try and catch but this hasn't worked since it doesn't throw an exception, it just gives a php warning like this:

```
[06-Aug-2010 19:59:42] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://new.mysite.com/ghs 1/) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  in /home/example/public_html/other/simple_html_dom.php on line 39
```

Line 39 is in the above code.

How can i correctly handle this error, can I just use a plain `if`condition, it doesn't look like it returns a boolean.

Thanks all for any help

### Update

Is this a good solution?

```
if(fopen(urlencode(trim("$next_url")), 'r')){

    $html3 = file_get_html(urlencode(trim("$next_url")));

}else{
    //do other stuff, error_logging
    return false;

}
```

Comment: why it is called via url, not filename?

Comment: @Col, its a remote file.

Comment: Somebody around here has an itchy downvote finger.

Comment: For the person that neg repped my question. Don't hide yourself, comment below as to why you think this question deserves a neg rep.

Comment: why it is remote file? why do you use fiesystem function to read an HTTP resource?

Comment: Well its a good question, so +1

Comment: @Abs It's probably because you are downvoting all answers for no reason.

Comment: @NullUserException - I have only down voted 2 questions, those coming up with solutions that suppress errors rather than handling them. Also that is NO reason to down vote the question at all. You probably don't see this now as some questions have been edited.

Comment: What do you think of my updated solution?

Comment: @Col - I am not sure why filesystem functions are used. You need to ask the guys who wrote the class I mentioned in my question. Mind you, its a popular class.

Comment: Use CURL. I don't understand why the lib you are using does not already use CURL to be honest. It should only fall back to file_get_contents() when the CURL lib is unavailable.

Comment: @Abs (and Col): How is using @ and the return code less legitimate 'error handling' than catching an exception, or the solution you currently have up there under 'Is this a good solution?'. Just because of the @?

Comment: See my updated answer. I also point out why error suppression is as valid as your solution.

Comment: @Col Thanks for downvoting my answer without reading the explanation as to why I used `@`

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives that actually use DOM instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
function fget_contents() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    // the @ can be removed if you lower error_reporting level
    $contents = @call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args);

    if ($contents === false) {
        throw new Exception('Failed to open ' . $file);
    } else {
        return $contents;
    }
}
```

Basically a wrapper to `file_get_contents`. It will throw an exception on failure.
To avoid having to override `file_get_contents` itself, you can

```
// change this
$dom->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true); 
// to
$dom->load(call_user_func_array('fget_contents', $args), true);
```

Now you can:

```
try {
    $html3 = file_get_html(trim("$link")); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle error here
}
```

Error suppression (either by using `@` or by lowering the error_reporting level is a **valid** solution. This can throw exceptions and you can use that to handle your errors. There are many reasons why `file_get_contents` might generate warnings, and PHP's manual itself recommends lowering error_reporting: [See manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: You can capture the output of @file_get_contents... If it's === FALSE, then you can throw your own exception, set a return code, or whatever.

Comment: @quantumSoup: Be aware that your first example `if(file_get...` will give an error if an empty file is read successfully, whereas the second one `if($contents === false)` will only return an error if there really is an error.

Comment: @gross Yes, I forgot to check for identical to false on the first one. Got rid of the whole first part though.

Comment: @quantumSoup - I have tried the above after editing the simplehtmldom calss, view it here: http://pastebin.com/5TrEJqQF - I get the error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare fget_contents

Comment: @Abs Apparently you have a `fget_contents` declared somewhere. Rename the function to `fgc_with_exception`, `file_get_exception`, or whatever (and rename the call in the library accordingly)

Comment: @Abs Here's the [modified class](http://pastebin.com/TeNXUiTW), and here's a [usage example](http://pastebin.com/cG7EX6GM). It works here.

Comment: @quantumSoup - Thanks, I couldn't find another function with the same name, but I have renamed `fget_contents_893`. However, it is always throwing an exception and my script that use to take hours to complete finishes within 10 seconds. Its not returning any html. I am checking what the problem is now, any ideas?

Comment: Strange, it seems file_get_contents doesn't like encoded urls. I have removed that and it seems to be executing fine.

Comment: Well this has been a rough question, at least its working now. Thank you very much quantumSoup for your continued help. :)

Comment: @Abs Indeed, you are not supposed to pass encoded URL's to any of PHP's file functions

Comment: I'm passing in a url with query params, but the error message is printing out as if i passed it an encoded url `&amp;` could that be indicative of a problem?  I define the url exactly the line before making the call, and its not encoded there. Note, the errors are only sporadic, I thought it was just the API, now I wonder based on @Abs comment on this.

Answer (score 4):

Use [CURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the URL and handle the error response that way.

Simple example from [curl_init()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php):

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: So the idea is to check the URL first before passing it to file_get_contents, I think that is a good idea. I think its better to use fopen. See my update, what do you think?

Comment: No, CURL will return the contents for you so there will be no need for a subsequent file_get_contents.

Comment: You'll be interested in CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER in curl_setopt(): http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: I can not use the CURL or fopen to get the contents. I need to still make use of the file_get_contents provided by the API, I just need a check to see if file_get_contents hasn't returned an error and do something if it has. Again, I can not directly fiddle with file_get_contents as it is within the API of simplehtmldom like I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: I would just override that method in the library in my own class as its behaviour is clearly unsuitable in this instance.

Comment: +1  Use CURL where available for all HTTP requests...  It's designed for it...  `file_get_contents` will work (in most cases), but it's not designed for HTTP, so it'll be quite hard to detect certain types of errors, etc...

Answer (score 2):

From my POV, good error handling is one of the big challenges in PHP. Fortunately you can register your own Error Handler and decide for yourself what to do.

You can define a fairly simple error handler like this:

```
function throwExceptionOnError(int $errorCode , string $errorMessage) {
    // Usually you would check if the error code is serious
    // enough (like E_WARNING or E_ERROR) to throw an exception
    throw new Exception($errorMessage);
}
```

and register it in your function like so:

```
function file_get_html() {
    $dom = new simple_html_dom;
    $args = func_get_args();
    set_error_handler("throwExceptionOnError");
    $dom->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);
    restore_error_handler();
    return $dom;
}
```

- For an exhaustive list of error codes see http://php.net/manual/errorfunc.constants.php
- For a complete documentation of set_error_handler, see 
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 1):

To see why a file_get_contents call might have failed, you could just use php's error_get_last function:

```
if ($contents = file_get_contents($url)) {
    // it worked
}
else {
   die("Failed to fetch ".$url.", error: ".error_get_last()['message']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you're fetching from an external URL the best handling is going to come from the introduction of HTTP library like Zend_Http. This isnt much different than using CURL or fopen except its going to extract the particulars of these "drivers" into a universal API and then you can choose which you want to use. Its also going to have some built in error trapping to make it easier on you.

If you dont want the overhead of another library then you can code it yourself obviously - in which case i always prefer CURL.