# How to handle page scraping errors with Simple HTML Dom Parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom, codeigniter, web-scraping

Similar to Facebook, I am building an app that allows users to post a link.

The user fills out the link in an input field, and the controller returns

```
Title
Link
Meta description
Images (as thumbnails)
```

to the view.

Here is the controller code:

```
    $url = $this->input->post('posts_link');

    if (!empty($url)) {

        $html = file_get_html($url);

        foreach ($html->find('img') as $element) {

          $src = "";

          $src = $element->src;

            if (preg_match("/\.jp[e]?g$/i", $src)) {

            $images[] = $src;

            }
        }

        $data['posts_link'] = $url;
        $data['images']     = $images;
        $data['title']          = $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
        $data['meta']           = get_meta_tags($url);
```

The problem I'm having is when there are no images, no title, or no description (alone or in combination).

I am using codeigniter and it throws several errors on the view, which I would rather have suppressed.

Is there a best practice to suppress these errors or place empty variables in case no title/images/descriptions are returned by the DOM parser?

For example I've tried

`$data['images'] = $images ? $images : '';`

but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: And what is the *actual* problem?

Comment: The problem I'm having is when there are no images, no title, or no description (alone or in combination).

I am using codeigniter and it throws several errors on the view, which I would rather have suppressed.

Comment: @torr: **what errors**? We need to guess?

Comment: :0P - sorry - Undefined index: description, Undefined variable: images, are a few examples

Comment: @torr: so predefine them `$images = array(); $description = '';`

Comment: @zerkms, I've tried `$data = array()` and it didn't work - should I predefine each array key as in `$data['images'] = array()`?

Comment: @torr: no, you need to predefine **used variables**. Added separate answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to predefine the variables before you use them. For `$images` it would be

```
$images = array();
```

right after `if (!empty($url)) {` etc

Comment: this works of $images, but how to resolve the undefined index error coming from `description`? since `$meta` is an array in itself, I retrieve description via `$meta['description']` in the view, but how to initialize this one in the controller?

Comment: @torr: `if (isset($meta['description'])) { // work with description }`

Comment: what would you suggest to suppress an error like this -- `Message: file_get_contents(http://cia.gov) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!` -- certain websites that don't have `<title>` seem to break `file_get_contents`, regardless if I run the function directly or via Simple Dom Parser

Comment: @torr: `failed to open stream` has nothing to do with non existent title

Comment: OK thanks - found this on SO that may help other with same issue -- [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431169/good-error-handling-with-file-get-contents)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array_key_exists('images', $data)) {
    // display the image
    }
else
{

    //set a default image, etc
}
```

or something like [isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: he has an issues in *filling* `$data` array, not in its reading :-S

Answer (score -1):

you can suppress errors by using the @ symbol. i.e.

```
 @     $data['images']     = $images;
```

Comment: The worst advice ever. You have a headache? Decapitate it, lol.

Comment: I really wanted to avoid the use of `@`