# Error Handling in simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php

I am a beginner in PHP and I have a similar problem to that handled in:

[Good error handling with file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431169/good-error-handling-with-file-get-contents)

In simple_html_dom.php, there is a function called load_file, which is:

```
    function load_file() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $this->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);
    }
```

In my PHP script, I use this function as:

$html->load_file($link);

When I try to load a broken link, I get a warning message on my output display like:

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.yurowdesigns.com/UkraineSIG/test.asp) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/yurow/wwwroot/yurowdesigns.com/programs/simple_html_dom.php on line 568

I would like to re-route this and similar error messages to an error.log file on my website rather than having it on my output display.

I naively tried to adapt the answer given in

[Good error handling with file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431169/good-error-handling-with-file-get-contents)

to my problem by adding the the function fget_contents() to my copy of simple_html_dom.php.

```
function fget_contents() {
$args = func_get_args();
// the @ can be removed if you lower error_reporting level
$contents = @call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args);

if ($contents === false) {
    throw new Exception('Failed to open ' . $file);
} else {
    return $contents;
}
}
```

And changed line 568 in load_file to read:

$this->load(call_user_func_array('fget_contents', $args), true);

But now, when I run my PHP script, I get a new error message:

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'fget_contents' not found or invalid function name in /home/yurow/wwwroot/yurowdesigns.com/programs/simple_html_dom.php on line 568

Which means that simple_html_dom.php does not recognize the function 'fget_contents'

Where did I go wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code :

```
function load_file() {
    try{
       $args = func_get_args();
       $this->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      print_r(e);
    }
}
```

Here as you see it has try and catch block that will handle the errors.

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav.  I will try your solution, but I found another answer.  It turns out that the function fget_contents() works fine, but I was putting it in the wrong place in the simple_html_dom.php script.  It belongs in the "helper functions" section of the script, not in the "class simple_html_dom{" section.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, in your PHP files, set them up to hide errors from being displayed. Use `ini_set('display_errors','1');` and then log your errors using [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) or hopefully your default php.ini config already logs errors using the [`error_log` string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)

Comment: Indranil: Please see my response to Gaurav Vashishtha.