# Handle errors file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, twitter, file-get-contents

I'm writing an application that uses a .php script to get tweets using the twitter search API.
See below code:

```
<?php
$hashtag = 'hashtag'; // We search Twitter for the hashtag
$show = 25; // And we want to get 25 tweets
// Local path
$cacheFile = '../../_data/tweets.json.cache'; // A cachefile will be placed in _data/


$json = file_get_contents("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?result_type=recent&rpp=$show&q=%23" . $hashtag. "%20-RT") or die("Could not get tweets");
$fp = fopen($cacheFile, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $json);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

My problem is that I want to make sure that this script runs without fail, or if it does fail at least doesn't keep looping.

The script is going to be run automatically every 1 minute.
Would anyone know a good way to handle errors here?

TL;DR: How do I handle errors on my code?

Comment: How about some exception handling... http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

Comment: Here is the best answer which can help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431169/good-error-handling-with-file-get-contents?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in simple, use '@' prefix for function. It suppresses errors from displaying. [Read More Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

```
<?php
$hashtag = 'hashtag'; // We search Twitter for the hashtag
$show = 25; // And we want to get 25 tweets
$cacheFile = '../../_data/tweets.json.cache'; // A cachefile will be placed in _data/
$json = @file_get_contents("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?result_type=recent&rpp=$show&q=%23" . $hashtag . "%20-RT");
if (!empty($json)) {
  $fp = fopen($cacheFile, 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $json);
  fclose($fp);
} else {
  echo "Could not get tweets";
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I can sleep safely knowing my code won't explode itself.