# Catching JSON-Errors?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i am searching for a simple way to catch JSON-Errors and put out my own Errormessage. To give you an example, i have code that looks like this:

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

This works totally fine, but after while the URL does not contain more content. I know that, and it is totally fine, but i do not want that an error gets thrown all the time that looks like this:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://example.com/getcontent.php): failed
>   to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST in
>   C:\Program Files... on line 153

The first thing i tried was to make a try/catch-statement which looked like this:

```
try
{
    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error!";
}
```

This did not change anything.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Take a look into this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431169/good-error-handling-with-file-get-contents ... there are some methods described which can be adapted to your needs.

Comment: check out [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php), may shed some light too

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you very much for your fast responses to my question. I did realize that i was to quick in posting that question and i did not read carefully enough. I thought the error was produced by JSON_DECODE but in fact it was FILE_GET_CONTENTS! So when i searched for this i already found a perfect answer here on this site:

[How can I handle the warning of file_get_contents() function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php)

Thank you all very much again.